# Is characteristic temperature $T_0$ of a semiconductor laser geometry independent?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, laser, photonics

Can I compare $T_0$ of one laser to another one, with different length and width?

For example, let's say there are two lasers:

- Laser A

  - Width: 20 $\mu m$
  - Length: 500 $\mu m$
  - $T_0$: X
- Laser B

  - Width: 50 $\mu m$
  - Length: 1000 $\mu m$
  - $T_0$: Y

So if $T_0$'s vary, can I say, that e.g. that A and B have different material quality, different quantum wells etc? Or maybe, for those two geometries $T_0$ tells us nothing, because geometry also influences the $T_0$?

I think I can make such comparisons, because two specialists from newport [(in this article)](https://www.laserdiodecontrol.com/laser-diode-parameter-overview) use threshold current *densities* do find $T_0$, but I just want to make sure.